# Code Injection using mach_star

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, finder, code-injection

I was trying to inject code into the Finder process using mach_inject  . I am currently using given the source given [here](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_star/)

The code seems to get the PID of the finder process correctly. There is a bundle `mach_inject_bundle` which is to be injected.

The following error comes every time I run the injector.

```
mach_inject failing.. (os/kern) invalid address
error: (os/kern) invalid address
```

I am running the build using `sudo` from the terminal.  I am using Snow Leopard MAC OS X 10.6.8.

I found some similar issues reported by others [here](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_star/issues/23) . But no solution seems to work.
Can someone please help me out ?? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Architectures setting for the project just set `x86_64`.